# Large error in errorbar with logscale

Tags: pgfplots

In the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ymode=log, ymin=0.005, ymax=0.1]
        \addplot [mark=diamond]
        plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
        table [x=x, y=y, y error=y-err]{%
          x y y-err
          0 0.070 0.003
          1 0.026 0.001
          2 0.018 0.001
          3 0.012 0.02
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error of the last point is too large so that the error bar should span from `-0.008` to `0.022`. However, because I am plotting in log-scale, the lower bound is completely gone, as shown below.
In standard plotting libraries (like MATLAB or matplotlib), the lower error bar usually extends until below as far as `ymin`.

I know that one way to fix this is to to use `y error minus=y-min, y error plus=y-max` and choose an appropriate `y-min`. However, I am wondering if there is a better way, since this requires modifying all the points even though only one is problematic. Better yet, is there a way to fix the behavior of `error bars`?

[image: Wrong error-bar in log-scale]

Example Python code that produces the correct plot (MATLAB is similar):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x = np.arange(0,4)
y = [0.070, 0.026, 0.018, 0.012]
yerr= [0.003, 0.001, 0.001, 0.02]
plt.yscale('log') 
plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=yerr, fmt='-o')
plt.xlim([-1, 4]); plt.ylim([0.005, 0.1])
plt.show()
```

[image: correct python output]

Comment: What is the expected output? **0.012 minus 0.02 is -0.008** and I think that you can't use a negative number as an argument for a log function.

Comment: Yes indeed. I am looking for output that is similar to `matplotlib` or MATLAB, where the lower error bar extends as far as `ymin` (to signify that the error is beyond the axis limits).

Comment: Independent of LaTeX: I would check my assumptions if I would have a situation like this. If it's just one problematic value then maybe you can differentiate between upper and lower error bars and limit the lower one to the value itself (0.012 in this case). But maybe the tikz guys here have a better solution.

Comment: As I mention in my question, that's one possible way, except that I don't know how to specify upper and lower limits for a single point while specifying the error for the other points. Differentiating between upper and lower points for all the points (even the non-problematic ones) seems to be an overkill.

Comment: possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your data table you could use PGFPlots "expr" feature to calculate whether you have passed 0 or not and "limit" the error bar length (use first `\addplot` block with the corresponding "blue" plot). If you also want to emphasize the error bars that would end in the negative region you have to add a second `\addplot` (as was already shown in [Symbol 1's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357036/95441) at a similar question (use the second `\addplot` block with the corresponding "red" plot).

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    % either store the data in an external file or create a loaded table for
    % the "better" solution, so you don't have to repeat the data table
    \pgfplotstableread{
        x   y     y-err
        0.1 0.070 0.003
        1.1 0.026 0.001
        2.1 0.018 0.001
        3.1 0.012 0.02
    }{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymode=log,
        ymin=0.005,
        ymax=0.1,
    ]

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % just limit error bar length to "zero"
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        \addplot+ [
            mark=diamond,
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit,
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            % (nothing special needed here)
            y error plus=y-err,
            % limit error bar to end at `ymin'
            y error minus expr={
                ifthenelse(
                    \thisrow{y} - \thisrow{y-err} <= 0,
                    \thisrow{y} - 1e-4,
                    \thisrow{y-err}%
                )
            },
        ] {
            x y     y-err
            0 0.070 0.003
            1 0.026 0.001
            2 0.018 0.001
            3 0.012 0.02
        };

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % use different styles for error bars ending in the positive region
        % and for error bars ending in the negative region
        % (inspired by <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357036/95441>)
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        % only draw the limited negative error bars (in another style)
        \addplot+ [
            % use `forget plot' so it doesn't count for the cycle list or the
            % legend entries
            forget plot,
            % it should be invisible except for the negative error bar
            draw=none,
            mark=none,
            error bars/.cd,
                % limit it for the negative error bar
                y dir=minus,
                y explicit,
                % don't draw a marker at the end
                error mark=none,
                % and optionally also use another style
                error bar style={
                    dashed,
                },
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            y error expr={
                ifthenelse(
                    % calculate if the error bar would end in the negative region
                    \thisrow{y} - \thisrow{y-err} <= 0,
                    % if yes, limit it to "zero" ...
                    \thisrow{y} - 1e-4,
                    % ... and don't draw the error bar otherwise
                    NaN%
                )
            },
        ] {\loadedtable};

        % draw the "normal" error bars
        \addplot+ [
            mark=diamond,
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit,
        ] table [
            x=x,
            y=y,
            y error=y-err,
        ] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I really like the solution with the expr. I am still relatively new to pgfplots but I know that I can create global styles that I can repeatedly used in multiple `addplot`s. Can this be done here? So that I don't have to repeat the `expr` for every plot.

Comment: Sure you can do this. But because the answer would be a bit longish for a comment and this was not requested in your question: Would you mind asking a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117)?

Comment: Thanks. I posted a follow-up [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417606)