# Combing multiple pgftable attributes as a single one

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

This is a follow-up from the question: [Large error in errorbar with logscale](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417420/large-error-in-errorbar-with-logscale/417443).

The following MWE plots some lines, and provides an `expr` for when the the error results in a negative value which would not be plotted at all by pgfplots.

```
documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{
  x   y     y-err
  0.1 0.070 0.003
  1.1 0.026 0.001
  2.1 0.018 0.001
  3.1 0.012 0.02
}{\loadedtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymode=log, ymin=0.005, ymax=0.1,]

    \addplot+ [
    mark=diamond,
    error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
    ] table [
    x=x,
    y=y,
    y error plus=y-err,     %% First `plus` is set to the error
    y error minus expr={    %% `minus` is set to an expression
      ifthenelse(
      \thisrow{y} - \thisrow{y-err} <= 0,
      \thisrow{y} - 1e-4,
      \thisrow{y-err}%
      )
    }] {\loadedtable};    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to declare the attributes

```
y error plus=y-err,
y error minus expr={
  ifthenelse(
  \thisrow{y} - \thisrow{y-err} <= 0,
  \thisrow{y} - 1e-4,
  \thisrow{y-err}%
  )
```

as some sort of style and use the resulting style in multiple plots?
Ideally, I am hoping for something like this

```
table [x=x, y=y, y err=y-err, fix-negative] { .... }
```

So far, by defining

```
\def\yerrminus#1#2{{ifthenelse(\thisrow{#1} - \thisrow{#2} <= 0,
                               \thisrow{#1} - 1e-4,
                               \thisrow{#2})}}
```

I am able to do this

```
table [x=x, y=y, y err plus=y-err, 
       y err minus expr=\yerrminus{y}{y-err}] { .... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like the following?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % create a custom style for the "special" error bars
        % the three arguments require the column names of
        % - 1   x column
        % - 2   y column
        % - 3   y minus error
        my y error bar style/.style n args={3}{
            error bars/y dir=both,
            error bars/y explicit,
            table/x=#1,
            table/y=#2,
            % (nothing special needed here)
            table/y error plus=#3,
            % limit error bar to end at `ymin'
            table/y error minus expr={
                ifthenelse(
                    \thisrow{#2} - \thisrow{#3} <= 0,
                    \thisrow{#2} - 1e-4,
                    \thisrow{#3}%
                )
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymode=log,
        ymin=0.005,
        ymax=0.1,
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            mark=diamond,
            % use the created style here
            % (in the `\addplot' options and not in the `table' options)
            my y error bar style={x}{y}{y-err},
        ] table {
            x y     y-err
            0 0.070 0.003
            1 0.026 0.001
            2 0.018 0.001
            3 0.012 0.02
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: That's great. This is actually better than passing it to the table for me. Although I am not sure why the same concept doesn't work with tables. BTW, Is there a way to access the `ymin` of the axis (0.005 in this case) from inside `\pgfplotsset`? So that I don't have to make the style axis-specific.

Comment: I don't have any problems replacing the inline table by a "loaded table". And yes, you can access the `ymin` value exactly the same way as inside the `axis` environment by using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}`.